# Use "cell" in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can use "cell.text" in my CellForRowAtIndexPath, but when I try to use it at didSelectRowAtIndexPath it says undeclared "cell"

Do I have to declare it again or how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In the `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` callback you just don't have any `cell` reference. You can get it through `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` routine, like so:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //whatever you want to do with the cell
}
```

But anyway as you've created the cells earlier, you should be able to get the underlying data with the row from the `indexPath`. Something like that:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    SomeDataObject* object = [someDataArray objectAtIndex:row];
    //whatever you want to do with the data
}
```

Comment: The thing I need to do is: When you touch a cell, add some text with: cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"detail"; (to the right/detail)

Comment: then, this becomes a breakpoint: "-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"detail";
}"

Comment: What do you mean "this becomes a breakpoint"? Do you get some exception? Compilation time error? The text added to another cell? The text doesn't seem to be added at all?

Comment: I guess it doesn't know where to place the DetailText, because NSLog DOES work. Any ideas how to let it know where to place it?

Comment: What error exactly does it present? (I don't see any when I'm compiling)

Comment: BTW, how do you create those cells in `-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Ensure, that you did create them with right style like: `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];` otherwise you'll have no `detailTextLabel` in those cells.

Comment: One thing, how can I use an NSString in cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"detail";?

Comment: Hm... I don't understand the question actually. This: `cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"detail";` is how you setting the `detail` string into the `text` property of the `UILabel`. If you want to get that string then you need something like `NSString* string = cell.detailTextLabel.text;`...

Answer (score 0):

There should be no real need to try and access the cell in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You most likely have the data used to populate your table data stored in an `array` or similar so you should be able to access it from that `array` using the indexPath variable e.g. `[indexPath row]` (you may need to account for `[indexPath section]` too depending on your setup).